# Angular BehaviourSubject in UIService and 2 Components subscribing twice

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an app with 2 components app and home.

In app I have a side menu which when an item is clicked it updates a behaviorSubject in a UIService I am using as a simple store.

In home component I subscribe to the store and am currently just logging it to the console.

Every time I click a menu item the subscription in the home component is called twice. I have seen other answers to this using takeUntil or take.

The home component does not get destoyed so I can't use ngOnDestroy to unsubscribe.

If I use take(1) then it does not log anything.

**app.componnent.ts**

```js
    selectTechnique(technique){
      this.uiService.selectTechnique(technique)
    }
```

**ui-service.service.ts**

```js
    private _stateSource$ = new BehaviorSubject<UIState>({
       selectedTechniqueTitle: '',
    });
            
    state$ = this._stateSource$.asObservable();
        
    //Action

    selectTechnique(technique) {  
       this._stateSource$.next({
         ...this._getCurrentState(),
         selectedTechniqueTitle: technique.title,
       });
    }

    // Select
    
    selectSelectedTechnique() {
       return this.state$.pipe(map((state) => 
         state.selectedTechniqueTitle));
    }

    private _getCurrentState(): UIState {
        return this._stateSource$.value;
    }
```

**home.component.ts**

```js
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.uiService.selectSelectedTechnique().subscribe(val => {
        console.log('SelectedTechnique', val); // This logs twice
      })

    // or 

      this.uiService.selectSelectedTechnique().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(val => {
        console.log('SelectedTechnique', val); // This does not log anything
      })
    }
```

How can I only get the data once? I need to do a http get inside this subscription and I only want to do it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a `debounceTime`, if those changes happen soon after each other, but this is just a workaround.

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.uiService.selectSelectedTechnique()
    .pipe(debounceTime(500))
    .subscribe(val => {
      // do stuff
    })
}
```

I would rather focus on figuring out why is the technique changed twice. It obviously happens, it might cause issues in other components.

Comment: OK I used debounceTime(1) and it now only logs once. Thanks for the workaround. Lets see if I get any other answers. Thanks